# JavaFX Label not updating correctly the text

Tags: javafx, label, textarea

I am trying to create an application that connects to a Linux Virtual Machine (with `JSch`) and asks Linux a few questions about itself, like the OS name and kernel version. I have succeeded in that, and the application works..but only in the Eclipse console.

If i try to print it out on a Label, or TextArea ...weird things are happening. For example, if i try to print it out on a label, then it prints out only the last command. If i try it with TextArea then it prints out everything, but in one line, and i do not know how to brake the lines...

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML private TextField ip_text_field, username_text_field, password_text_field;
    @FXML private Label output;

    String ip, username, pass;


    private Main main;

    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getIP(){ip = ip_text_field.getText(); return ip;}
    public String getUsername(){username = username_text_field.getText(); return username;}
    public String getPassword(){pass = password_text_field.getText(); return pass;}

    public void connectButtonFunction(){                

        try{
            String command = "lsb_release -a | grep -i Description && uname -mrs";

            String host = getIP();
            String user = getUsername();
            String password = getPassword();

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);;
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();

            //System.out.println("Channel Connected to machine " + host + " server with command: " + command );

            try{
                InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
                String line = null;

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    //System.out.println(line);
                   output.setText(line);                

                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputReader.close();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();


        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
```

Here is  how it looks like with the label.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only shows the last command when you use `Label` is because `setText` rewrites the label text everytime.

So something like this would solve it:

```
String buffer = "";
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    buffer += line + "\n"; // assuming `line` doesn't end with a newline already           
 }
output.setText(buffer);
```

As for the `TextArea` problem (which you will also face in `Label`), you can enable text wrapping by calling `output.setWrapText(true)`

Note: you can call `appendText` instead of `setText` on `TextArea` without needing that extra buffer.